According to Catholics, is it lawful for a president's security team to search and frisk their church leaders?
A Catholic Diocese in a certain locality in my country invited the president to oversee the ordination of a certain episcopal rank, I was shocked to see the security team of the president lining up all episcopal authorities clothed in their service robes to frisk and search them to see if they posed any security threat to the president.
This exercise shows that the president and his team do not trust the Catholic Church leadership, why would the Catholic Church allow the public image and trust of their Church to be damaged this way for it would have been better if this leader didn't visit the church foe Christ and the Church is above all men including governments?

It does not necessarily imply that the security team don't trust the bishops. The policy is to search everyone whether trusted or not. Otherwise to search anyone would be tantamount to saying that they do not trust that person. Rather than say we trust you and you and you, but we trust you less so, the practice is often to search everybody.

If the president subsequently attends an event at which someone who is not 100% trusted is there, Security can search him and point out that they search everybody, even bishops.

@davidlol, why then go to a church whose leadership you don't trust, why not just remain at your premise or go to a church you trust?

Without knowing your country it is hard to say. In many cases a president may wish to attend events important to differing parts of the community, either out of duty or for electioneering purposes.  What if he said he didn't entirely trust Protestants or Muslims or Welsh Presbyterians so would not attend their events? In my country we have no president,  our king is governor of the national Church but still attends other communities events. In your country how it would go down if he said he only trusts Catholic bishops? But I like your question which has been an issue over centuries.

I think it just shows Humility on the part of the church leaders submitting themselves to these requirements. Not seeing themselves as "above" or better then others who do the same. Rather then kicking up a fuss. Simply himbily submit to the civil authority - keeping the peace and facilitating the event in a peaceful spirit.

@marshall, yes as it is written in the law fear God and honor the king

The president should fear God and fear the church because it represents God on earth. The president should respect the church because God is not to be messed with, God can make you pay like you have never seen before

I sometimes attend Mass in the Church where a former speaker/vp candidate attends and there were definitely some well defined protocols for him and his family.  There was one incident where a visiting priest left his backpack in the "wrong spot" and the bomb squad got called in.

@peterturner, it is really sad that even cardinals and church leaders are capable of great evil even after claiming to accept Jesus Christ into their hearts

@sof yeah, if you're talking about Cdl. Cupich - that is super sad, but I don't think that has anything to do with your question.  All I'm saying is that the protocols for politicians don't get abrogated because of a presumption that clerics are stellar human beings. Defensive protocols can protect both politicians, the public and the church.

@PeterTurner, true. They could trust the clerics whose hearts are only known to God and then they end up surprising the country and the world

According to Catholics, is it lawful for a president's security team to search and frisk their church leaders?
The short answer is yes.
You make the claim that ”this exercise shows that the president and his team do not trust the Catholic Church leadership.” This is absolutely not true!
Remember those pontifical trips of the late Pope St. John Paul II? Local authorities did this each time clergy were to come in close proximity of the Roman Pontiff with or without the local head of state being present. This is simple standard procedure and is based with good reasons. Pope John Paul was almost stabbed with a knife by a priest, who was concealing a it in his clothes while the pope was in Spain. It was the local authorities who dwelt with that situation. It works both ways!
The life of the President is a security issue and almost every State will have laws and protocols that are to be followed when a head of state is present at an event.
Speaking of searching, I can recall once attending a papal outdoor mass and the the local authorities searched everyone who came within a certain distance of the pope. It is simple protocol! The pope as a head of state and a president as a head of state are entitled to security details and procedures. One should not read into it as not trusting the Church, but as maintaining the security and safety of government officials at public events.
Sure one may say that the Church is above the government. But, the government has the rights and duties to to protect their heads of state. There is no bad will that should be implied here! After all Church officials are bound to follow the laws and regulations of the country they find themselves in.
Working together makes it that everyone is safe!
PS. Wonder what would have happened if a bishop did in fact did have a concealed weapon on his person. Historically, individuals have been caught masquerading as a bishop!

Everyone is capable of great good and great evil, pray for my country, there is so much civil unrest.
